# jQuery DataTables iterate over rows and change cell background

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am trying to iterate over all cells in a column (column index 1) in a DataTable and change the background color based on cell value using the following code:

```
var table = $('#my_table').DataTable( {...});
console.log("next, iterate over rows in table: "+table);
table.rows().every( function ( rowIdx, tableLoop, rowLoop ) { 
    console.log("looping over rows");
    var cell = table.cell({ row: rowIdx, column: 1 }).node();
    if (cell.data() == 'mouse'){
        $(cell).css('background-color', 'orange');
    }
});
console.log("finished iterating over rows ");
```

The table is displaying the data fine. 
However the console log prints:

```
>>next, iterate over rows, table: [object Object]
>>finished iterating over rows
```

ie the

```
table.rows().every( function (...){...}
```

is not entered. I copied and pasted from DataTables examples and I have no idea why it is not being executed.

The only thing I can think of is that the DataTables docs here: https://datatables.net/reference/api/rows().every() mention- Iterate over each **selected** row. None of the rows in the table are **selected**, I just want to loop through every row (and change cell color) regardles if it is selected or not.

Note I also tried:

```
table.rows().eq(0).each( function ( index ) {
    var row = table.row( index );
    var data = row.data();
    console.log(data)
});
```

And this is not executed either (console.log doesn't print anything from inside the function).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate over the table's **td** elements and capture the text content of each cell.

Apply some logic to these and you can easily assign each cell's background colour.

I have used arr.map() as it's ES6 JavaScript, but .each() works too.

```
$('table td').map(function(i, cell) {
    var cellContent = $(cell).text();
    console.log(i,cellContent);  // for demonstration
    if (cellContent === 'pending') $(cell).css('background-color', '#ccc');
});
```

This can be easily changed to get the cell element's data, class, or id too.

Comment: I have several tables on the page so this won't work. I tried selecting just my table but I don't know how to select the td as well eg $('#my_table td') but that didn't work.

Comment: I had to add your code inside a "fnInitComplete": function (oSettings, json) {} block within the DataTable declaration.